# Why am i getting Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax

```
for (post of posts) { //Posts are returned from a python django function                                        
  let readMore = '';
  let postDesc = post.fields.description
  if (post.fields.description.length > 227) {
    readMore = `<p class="btn btn-link" onclick="this.innerHTML = ${postDesc}"> Read more</p>`;
  };
  output += `<p class="card-text" style="white-space: pre-line;">${post.fields.description.substring(0, 227)} ${readMore}</p>`;

}
```

But when I click the read more button:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifierlocalhost:8000:1:22
```

I tried to remove the onclick and replace it with this at the end:

```
$('#mainPosts').append(output)

function showMore() {
  $('.readMore').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().html(`<br> ${post.fields.description}`)
  })
}
let g = document.createElement('script');
let s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
g.text = showMore();
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s)
```

But the problem is it's not replacing the substring current post description with the full one, it's replacing it with the very last post full description in the list!

Comment: `onclick="this.innerHTML = I'm a description">` - What is missing here? You have to wrap `${postDesc}` in quotes, or even better don't use inline JS for this (-> `.addEventListener()`)

Answer (score 0):

Change `onclick="this.innerHTML = ${postDesc}` to `onclick="this.innerHTML = '${postDesc}'`.

Let's examine how the current template string will be expanded, if `postDesc == "hello world"`:

`` <p class="btn btn-link" onclick="this.innerHTML = hello world"> Read more</p>`; ``. When the JavaScript VM tries to execute `this.innerHTML = hello world`, it recognizes `hello` as an undefined identifier, which will be tolerated, but then it encounters `world`, another undefined identifier, which is unexpected at this point, hence the error `unexpected token: identifier`.

As Andreas pointed out, a single quote in postDesc will cause problems. Here is a workaround for this: `onclick="this.innerHTML = '${postDesc.replace(/([\"\'])/g,'\$1')}'`.

Comment: This will only work as long as there's no single quote in `postDesc` -> don't use inline JS